Critical points multivariable real polynomials bounded from below
Must a multivariable real polynomial, which is bounded from below, have a critical point?
There are examples with no minimum, but I do not know any example without a critical point.
Of course, I mean on the whole ambient space R^n.

What is creating the boundary?  Is it a domain restriction like $[0, 1] \times [0, 1]$ or are we considering the polynomial on $\mathbb{R} \times \mathbb{R}$ or $\mathbb{R} ^n$?
Off the top of my head I would say depending on the domain it could go either way.

Note: I didn't downvote or close.  I think those who did are rude to do so without commenting.

As written, the answer is no.  Neither multivariable polynomials nor single variable polynomials with a lower bound are required to have a critical value.
Example:
$$ f(x,y) = 100- x^2 -y^2$$ on the domain $[1,5] \times [1,5]$ has no critical values on the domain, but has a lower bound given the domain.
Note: the function has a minimum, but minimums can occur on the domain boundaries without being a critical value.
